# Can I use slider dropouts on my track dropouts?

Tags: disc-brake, single-speed, conversion, dropouts, derailleur-hanger

My bike's dropout/fork-end basically look like this:

[image]

and I wonder if I could use something like this to convert it into a vertical dropout with a hanger and disc caliper mount:

[image]

I'll only be using the bike for road purposes. I suppose there shouldn't be any stress-related problems, right?

Comment: 1. What is the dropout spacing on the frame? 2. Do you want derailleur and disk brake fitted  and 3. Are you trying to save money?

Comment: 1. What do you mean about the dropout spacing? I just have the standard horizontal dropouts like in every singlespeed bike.

2. Yes.

3.No, but the frame is sentimental.

Comment: @Swifty approximately 115mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your rear spacing measures 115mm it might actually be designed as 110mm or 120mm. See [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html) for standard hub spacings.

120mm freewheel hubs should be available, but you will only be able to fit a 5 speed freewheel onto it. If the frame is 100mm and steel you can probably expand the spacing to 120mm - see the page linked above for how that is done.

You will not be able to buy a 120mm hub with a disc rotor attachment. Disc rotors take up space, so hubs and frames had to get wider to accommodate them and keep the spoke flanges separated enough to maintain wheel strength.

Personally, I wouldn't trust a disc brake conversion kit period, especially one that relies on a couple of tabs in the slot dropout to resist braking torque like the one you included a picture of. A decent set of rim brakes should be plenty powerful enough.

Also, the kit pictured moves the rear wheel attachment out of the actual frame dropouts. Again, I wouldn't trust that particular kit. There are slot dropout derailleur hangers available that keep the axle bolted in the frame.